# Displaying all the attributes of first UserData element of each Occurence corresponding to occurenceRefs?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a following code , I want to display all the attributes of first UserData element of each Occurence corresponding to occurenceRefs ? Actually i want to display this in the HTML format and i am not able to loop through the attributes and display them individually 
Thanks in advance .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ?>
<!-- GENERATED BY: PLM XML SDK 7.0.2.173 -->
<PLMXML xmlns="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema"
 schemaVersion="6" language="en-us" date="2012-03-23" languages="en-us" time="07:54:04" >
<Header id="id1" traverseRootRefs="#id7" transferContext="CRF_ITM_RPT_TMODE_INST"></Header>
<RevisionRule id="id2" name="Latest Working">
<Description>Latest Working else Latest Any Status</Description>
<ApplicationRef version="QQO9hJBI40bQ2C" application="Teamcenter" label="QQO9hJBI40bQ2C"></ApplicationRef></RevisionRule>
<ProductView id="id4" ruleRefs="#id2" rootRefs="id7" primaryOccurrenceRef="id7">
<ApplicationRef application="Teamcenter" label="BgE9Vysa40bQ2C/QQO9hJBI40bQ2C/AAAAAAAAAAAAAA/BOM"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id3" type="TC Specific Properties">
<UserValue value="imprecise" title="BOM_precision_type"></UserValue></UserData>
<Occurrence id="id7" occurrenceRefs="id11 id15 ">
<ApplicationRef application="Teamcenter" label="BgE9Vysa40bQ2C/"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id6">
<UserValue value="" title="rox9DesignItemID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="rox9CommrclDesignItemID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="rox9DesignRevision"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="rox9CommrclDesignRevision"></UserValue></UserData>
<UserData id="id8" type="AttributesInContext">
<UserValue value="" title="AO_ID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="SequenceNumber"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="OccurrenceName"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="Quantity"></UserValue></UserData>
<Transform id="id5">1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1</Transform></Occurrence>
<Occurrence id="id11" parentRef="#id7">
<ApplicationRef application="Teamcenter" label="BgE9Vysa40bQ2C/BsC9Vysa40bQ2C/"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id10">
<UserValue value="" title="rox9DesignItemID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="ROXD00216480" title="rox9CommrclDesignItemID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="rox9DesignRevision"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="A" title="rox9CommrclDesignRevision"></UserValue></UserData>
<UserData id="id12" type="AttributesInContext">
<UserValue value="" title="AO_ID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="10" title="SequenceNumber"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="OccurrenceName"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="Quantity"></UserValue></UserData>
<Transform id="id9">1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1</Transform></Occurrence>
<Occurrence id="id15" parentRef="#id7">
<ApplicationRef application="Teamcenter" label="BgE9Vysa40bQ2C/BsG9Vysa40bQ2C/"></ApplicationRef>
<UserData id="id14">
<UserValue value="ROXD00315587" title="rox9DesignItemID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="rox9CommrclDesignItemID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="C" title="rox9DesignRevision"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="rox9CommrclDesignRevision"></UserValue></UserData>
<UserData id="id16" type="AttributesInContext">
<UserValue value="" title="AO_ID"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="20" title="SequenceNumber"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="OccurrenceName"></UserValue>
<UserValue value="" title="Quantity"></UserValue></UserData>
<Transform id="id13">1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1</Transform></Occurrence>
```

---

I have understood a lot and able to fetch and display them but i want to them to display as written below , So the problem is i dont know how to loop over them individually or we may have to use templates and call them repetitively .......
Any help is appreciated.Please refer to code above

Thanks in advance
 The required output is:

```
rox9DesignItemID  rox9CommrclDesignItemID  rox9DesignRevision  rox9CommrclDesignRevision


                ROXD00216480                                        A 


 ROXD00315587                                 C
```

---

This below is the code for the above XML file . I am almost done with it , I am getting the occurenceRefs in a sequence in occid in the creCLext template and i have verified it by displaying it . The problem is the attributes of UserValue in the same template are not being displayed and i am not able to figure out whats the problem , is there anything wrong with xpath ? What is the correct Xpath to display attributes in creCLext template ?

Thanks in advance

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->  
<xsl:variable name="trvrootref" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Header/@traverseRootRefs"/>
<xsl:variable name="roid" select="substring-after($trvrootref,'#')"/>
<xsl:variable name="roe" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/plm:Occurrence[@id=$roid]"/>
<xsl:variable name="roe1" select="$roe/@occurrenceRefs"/>
<xsl:variable name="rprid" select="substring-after($roe/@instancedRef,'#')"/>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductRevision[@id=$rprid]"/>
<!-- Reference to the Site element and last name attribute  -->    
<xsl:variable name="site" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:Site"/>   
<xsl:variable name="site_name" select="$site/@name"/>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->  
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
     <title>Global Teamcenter - BOM Report</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayDate()
            {
             var d=new Date();
             var weekday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
             var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
             document.write(monthname[d.getMonth()] + " ");
             document.write(d.getDate() + ", ");
             document.write(d.getFullYear() + " ");
             document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + " ");
            }
      </script>
</head>
<body style="background-position: 21px 0px; font-size: 10pt; color: black; font-family: Verdana; background-color: white;" lang="en-us">
<div> </div>       
<div align="left"> </div>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->  
<div align="center">
<table style="table-layout: fixed; border-width: medium; border-style: none; border-color: -moz-use-text-color; font-size: 10pt; width: 653px; font-family: Verdana; border-collapse: collapse; word-wrap: break-word;" border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 271px;" width="271"></col>
        <col style="width: 24px;" width="24"></col>
        <col style="width: 358px;" width="358"></col>
    </colgroup>

<tbody valign="top"> 

<tr style="min-height: 42px;">
    <td colspan="3" style="border-width: 1pt 1pt 5pt; border-style: none none solid; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172) rgb(153, 168, 172) rgb(81, 125, 191); color: rgb(235, 240, 249); background-color: rgb(30, 60, 123); text-align: left;" width="653">
        <h6 align="center" style="margin-top: 0px; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 0px; color: rgb(235, 240, 249);">
            <font face="Verdana" size="4">ISE GTc Monthly User Report</font>
        </h6>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr style="min-height: 42px;">
    <td colspan="3" style="border-width: 5pt 1pt 1pt; border-style: solid none none; border-color: rgb(81, 125, 191) rgb(153, 168, 172) rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); text-align: left;" width="653">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="1">Generated by:</font>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <span title="Issue Title" id="L042502201095146C" style="border-right: 1pt none rgb(220, 220, 220); min-height: 18px; padding: 1px; border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(220, 220, 220); display: inline-block; margin: 1px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;"> 
                  Atul Kumar
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr style="min-height: 42px;">
    <td style="border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); text-align: left;" width="271">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="1">Date:</font>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <span title="Opened By"  id="L042586E014BA9B4F" style="border-right: 1pt none rgb(220, 220, 220); min-height: 18px; padding: 1px; border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(220, 220, 220); display: inline-block; margin: 1px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                  displayDate()
                 </script>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249);" width="24">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">   </font>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); text-align: left;" width="358">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="1">Site Name:</font>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>
                <span title="" id="L042587201D05A9D5" style="padding: 1px; display: inline-block; margin: 1px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); white-space: normal; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: window; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                <xsl:value-of select="$site_name"/>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>   

</tr>

<tr style="min-height: 38px;">
    <td style="border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); text-align: left;" width="271">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="1">Author Licenses:</font>
        </div>
        <div>
        <span>
            <span title="Area Owner" id="L0425876018E022B2" style="padding: 1px; min-height: 18px; display: inline-block; margin: 1px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); white-space: normal; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//plm:UserValue[@title = 'license_level' and @value= '0' and @type='int'])"/>
            </span>
        </span>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td style="border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249);" width="24">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">   </font>
        </div>
    </td>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->  
    <td style="border-width: 1pt; border-style: none; border-color: rgb(153, 168, 172); color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); text-align: left;" width="358">
        <div>
            <font face="Verdana" size="1">Consumer Licenses:</font>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>
                <span title="" id="L042587201D05A9D5" style="padding: 1px; display: inline-block; margin: 1px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); white-space: normal; text-overflow: ellipsis; background-color: window; text-align: left; word-wrap: normal;">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//plm:UserValue[@title = 'license_level' and @value= '1' and @type='int'])"/>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>   
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div>
    <span title="" id="" style="padding: 1px; overflow-x: hidden; margin: 1px; width: 647px; text-overflow: ellipsis; word-wrap: break-word;">
    </span>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <table title="" style="table-layout: fixed; border-width: medium; border-style: none; border-color: -moz-use-text-color; font-size: 10pt; width: 651px; font-family: Verdana; border-collapse: collapse; word-wrap: break-word;" border="1">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width: 200px;" width="200"></col>
            <col style="width: 160px;" width="160"></col>
            <col style="width: 100px;" width="100"></col>
            <col style="width: 185px;" width="185"></col>
        </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="">
            <td style="color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); border-width: 1pt; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(81, 125, 191); vertical-align: top;" width="173">rox9DesignItemID</td>
            <td style="color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); border-width: 1pt; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(81, 125, 191); vertical-align: top;" width="253">rox9CommrclDesignItemID</td>
            <td style="color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); border-width: 1pt; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(81, 125, 191); vertical-align: top;" width="118">rox9DesignRevision</td>
            <td style="color: black; background-color: rgb(235, 240, 249); border-width: 1pt; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(81, 125, 191); vertical-align: top;" width="173">rox9CommrclDesignRevision</td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
        <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="$roe1"/>
    </xsl:call-template> 
    </table>
</div>
<br/>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->  
<xsl:template name="genData">
<xsl:param name="curPart"/>
<xsl:param name="occStr"/>
<xsl:param name="attStr"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- inside createCL otherwise occStr <xsl:value-of select="$occStr"/> -->  
<xsl:template name="createCL">
<xsl:param name="occStr"/>
<xsl:if test="$occStr!=''">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($occStr,' ')">
    <xsl:variable name="occid" select="substring-before($occStr,' ')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
                <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="$occid"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
                <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="substring-after($occStr,' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>

        <xsl:call-template name="creCLext">
            <xsl:with-param name="occid" select="$occStr"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Reference to the user element and user_id,status and license_level attribute  -->
<xsl:template name="creCLext">
<xsl:param name="occid"/>
    <!-- Reference to the user element and user_id,status and license_level attribute  -->
    <xsl:variable name="occname" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/plm:Occurence[@id=$occid]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute1" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[1]/@title"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute2" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[2]/@title"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute3" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[3]/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute4" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[4]/@value"/>
    <!-- Reference to the person element and last name attribute  -->             



   <!-- Displaying the values by row order -->
      <tr>
         <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="$attribute1"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$attribute2"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$attribute3"/>
         </td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$attribute4"/></td>
      </tr>           
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what yoy mean by 'corresponding to occurenceRefs?'. Here is an XSL that matches the first `UserData` of each `Occurrence`  (XPath: `plxml:Occurrence/plxml:UserData[1]`) and outputs all its attributes (XPath: `@*`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:plxml="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="plxml:Occurrence/plxml:UserData[1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'=',.)"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a variation of the same XSL that output each `UserValue` instead than each attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:plxml="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="plxml:Occurrence/plxml:UserData[1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="plxml:UserValue">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@title,'=',@value)"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT

Fix the template like this:

```
  <xsl:template name="creCLext">
    <xsl:param name="occid"/>
    <!-- Reference to the user element and user_id,status and license_level attribute  -->
    <xsl:variable name="occname" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ProductView/plm:Occurrence[@id=$occid]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute1" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[1]/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute2" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[2]/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute3" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[3]/@value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="attribute4" select="$occname/plm:UserData[1]/plm:UserValue[4]/@value"/>
    <!-- Reference to the person element and last name attribute  -->



    <!-- Displaying the values by row order -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$attribute1"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$attribute2"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$attribute3"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$attribute4"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can u help me with this , i have added the information below .Thanks in advance

Comment: `Occurrence` with two 'r'...and you were using twice `@title` instead than `@value`